# First time using lambda function on c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, lambda

Hello everyone this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow, so I'll be as descriptive as possible. I've been trying to wrap my head around the lambda function and I think that this would be an appropriate time to use the function.

I have an sql table with a column machineNo and another column named count as a flag of yes or no whether its counted or not.

My objective is to group columns based on the machineNo column in sql. I've returned the list from sql with no problems.

I have
Spot 2
Spot 1
Spot 1
Spot 1 
Spot 1

Its supposed to show e.g

lbl1.Text = 4
lbl2.Text = 1

```
    public void listlambda()
    {
        con.OpenConnection();
        List<string> mchno = con.LoadList("Select mchNo from tbl_mch_ability where count = 0", "mchNo");

        var num = mchno.GroupBy(n => n == "mchNo");

        lbl1.Text = mchno.GroupBy(m => m == "Spot 1").Count().ToString();
        lbl2.Text = mchno.GroupBy(m => m == "Spot 2").Count().ToString();
    }
```

I've tried a lot of examples from stack overflow but my label always shows two.

Comment: Change the group by as `var num = mchno.GroupBy(n => n);` Then change `lbl1.Text = num .Count(m => m == "Spot 1").ToString();` and same for `lbl2` as your query only returns one column.

Comment: Hey buddy I got this error though operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'igrouping<string, string>' and string

Comment: After the first GroupBy() (you need just one, as shown in the comment above), you can, for example, convert to Dictionary: `var dict = num.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());`, so you can test for specific keys: `if (dict.TryGetValue("Spot 1", out int value)) { lbl1.Text = value.ToString();
}`

Comment: Omg jimi and user1672994  thanks so much, how do I like feedbacks??

Comment: @JonathanJames if you want to adress someone personally/directly in your comment put simply an **@** before the name like I did it with you. We don't *like* contributions here, we upvote :) but nevertheless you will be able to upvote comments with enough reputation. I forgot how much you need. But I did it for you though

Comment: @JonathanJames- Posted my comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not apply `==` on `IGrouping`. You need to change the groupBy as

```
 var num = mchno.GroupBy(n => n);
```

and later the text box assignment as

```
lbl1.Text = num .Count(m => m == "Spot 1").ToString();
lbl2.Text = num .Count(m => m == "Spot 2").ToString();
```

Comment: `m` is an `IGrouping` here :) You could use something like: `num.Single(m => m.Key == "Spot 1").Count().ToString();` (just one possible way)

Comment: Maybe `num.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key == "Spot 1")?.Count().ToString();` is better.